# jQuery Accordion Tab - Link to site, not page content

Tags: jquery, html

I've currently have 5 tabs on my jQuery Accordion.  Clicking on them causes the content to appear like one would expect.  However I would also like to include links to external site.  To keep the style the same I would like to have them look like the accordion as well.  I could have the content contain a link saying click here, but I would rather have it just be an external link.  I was able to use the UI Widget and add the style from the accordion to make it match, however I have encountered two issues.  The first is that the UI-Widget tab doesn't do the mouse over effect like the accordion tabs.  The second is that the text in the UI-Widget tab will not align with the other tabs (also looking at it being the same when text size is increased in the browser.)

```
<a href="http://apple.com/">
<div class="ui-widget" style="margin: 0px 20px;">
    <div class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="margin: 0px; padding: .5em;">
        <h3 class="ui-helper-reset" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-extlink" style="float: left;"></span><a href="#">Apple</a></h3></div>
</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to attach a separate `click` event to the link element:

```
$("#linkId").click(function() {
    window.location.href = "http://apple.com/";
});
```

This way, the rest of the functionality stays the same and you get an external link. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5aws/1/) for more.

**UPDATE**

If you don't want the default accordion behavior for this link, you can turn off all other `click` events that can affect it. Something like:

```
$("#linkId").parentsUntil("#accordion").off("click");
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5aws/2/).

Comment: I would almost rather use a stylized UI-Widget because it would look the same and act like a link without the rollover feature.  With your method the link according will still open and show no content before quickly redirecting.

Comment: Additionally, you can override the accordion behavior by unbinding all other click events that affect this link. I will update the answer.

Comment: Even better.  Just use: '$(".link").parentsUntil("#accordion").off("click");'  No need to specify the link location in the javascript if it is already done in the href HTML.

Comment: True; if you use the second solution, you don't need the first one.